# How does Meteor create a unique MongoDB _id on the client side?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

According to [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/insert) about the `Mongo.Collection.insert()` function,

> insert will generate a unique ID for the object you pass, insert it in the database, and return the ID.

It also works asynchronously:

> If you do provide a callback, insert still returns the ID immediately.

Is there any guarantee that the generated _id is globally unique? How does Meteor's Minimongo generate such an _id on the client side?

Comment: my guess is http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random `Random.id([n])` is very similar

Comment: Probably like the official MongoDB https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

Comment: If you mean, "how does the client know that the `_id` is not already taken on the server" then I bet it's a good chunk of maths and a bit of luck =p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Meteor is open source you can see exactly how this is done.

- [README for random package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/random)
- [random.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/dc3cd6eb92f2bdd1bb44000cdd6abd1e5d0285b1/packages/random/random.js)

From the README:

> The random package provides several functions for generating random
>   numbers. It uses a cryptographically strong pseudorandom number
>   generator when possible, but falls back to a weaker random number
>   generator when cryptographically strong randomness is not available
>   (on older browsers or on servers that don't have enough entropy to
>   seed the cryptographically strong generator).
>
> `Random.id([n])` - Returns a unique identifier, such as
>   "Jjwjg6gouWLXhMGKW", that is likely to be unique in the whole world.
>   The optional argument n specifies the length of the identifier in
>   characters and defaults to 17.

The short answer is that Meteor uses cryptography (aka *maths* as per @Kyll) to generate a random id that should be globally unique across all objects in all mongo databases everywhere. The "luck" part is that there is a small chance that two objects could end up with the same id. Now the `_id` key is indexed unique in mongo so an insert would fail if there is a dupe. I suspect Meteor has error handling to deal with that possibility.

Comment: Thanks, now I sort-of understand.