# In meteor/mongo collections, is the _id field unique in its collection or in the entire database?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to check that if I use `_id` fields that refer to documents from different collections, I will never have a duplicate `_id`, i.e. used in 2 different collections inside the same database.

Using meteor (so both in minimongo and mongodb), is the `_id` field unique in its collection or in the entire database?

Comment: What way of generating `_id` values do you use? Are they auto-generated by Meteor? Please provide an example of an `_id` value.

Comment: Here is an example: `qhrEnh36tthTswiYv`. I assume this is generated by mongo. I use the `_id` values attached to every mongo document I produce using meteor.

Comment: No, this is generated by Meteor.

Comment: Ok, I guess this question answers mine, even if it is not really the same: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33332339/3793161 Bottom line: they are generated by meteor and they are unique among the whole database. Correct me if I'm wrong, and if you think I should flag my question as duplicate

Comment: I don't think you should mark your question as duplicate. This is a different question, and hopefully I have provided a satisfactory answer to it.

Comment: Yes you did. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_id` values you have in your database are generated by Meteor using [**`Random.id()`**](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/random). These are unique across all collections.

Please note that the uniqueness of `_id` values in MonogoDB is ensured on the collection level, meaning that there is always a unique index on the `_id` field for every collection. There is no MongoDB mechanism in place that would ensure `_id` uniqueness across collections.

In any case, it is quite a safe assumption that Meteor's random IDs will never collide.

Comment: As you said, this is a "safe assumption". But, still, that's an assumption. Are they guaranteed to be unique, or not (suppose I have millions and millions of documents and resources are not an issue)? I mean, is there a mechanism in place where if the Random.id() was already generated before that it will be skipped and a new one generated? Because, if not, then there *can* be collisions (even if they are unlikely, but, people have been known to win the lottery).

Comment: How can we make sure that the id Meteor generates would not collide with existing ones on a collection? (Throwing an error is not ok cause it would break the operation and prevent the data from being saved)